# I have a runtime error 3061 in this code CurrentDb.Execute

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, updates

I am having a run-time error `3061` in this code:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tblCategory]" & _
 " SET [Category]=" & Me.txtCat & _
 ", [Percentage]='" & Me.txtPer & "'" & _
 " WHERE [Category]=" & Me.txtCat.Tag
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is Percentage a number type? If field type is number do not use apostrophe delimiters. Use them for text type field. Why are you bothering to update Category?

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameterized queries to avoid the need of string concatenation and quote enclosure since you explicitly define the types in `PARAMETERS` clause, all for a readable and maintainable routine. Below assumes *Percentage* is a decimal number (i.e., double).

**SQL** *(save as a stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [CategParam] Text, [PctParam] Double, [CategTagParam] Text;
UPDATE [tblCategory]
SET [Category] = [CategParam], [Percentage] = [PctParam]
WHERE [Category]= [CategTagParam]
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdef![CategParam] = Me.txtCat
qdef![PctParam] = Me.txtPer
qdef![CategTagParam] = Me.txtCat.Tag

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```